# Unable to Marshal JSON to Complex Java Type using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, lombok

Am trying to marshal a JSON payload to a complex Java type using Gson and Java 1.8.

The dependency I am using for Gson:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
    <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

---

JSON Response Payload (which I am using to model my POJOs) is coming in as a String:

```
{
    "header":{
        "timestamp":"1932264786"
    },
    "entity":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "musician":{
                "genre":{
                    "type":"jazz"
                },
                "timestamp":"2593264786",
                "musician":{
                    "id":"23104"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Header.java:

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Header {
    private String timestamp;
}
```

---

Entity.java:

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Entity {

    private String id;

    @Data
    static class Musician {

        @Data
        static class Genre {
            private String type;
        }

        @Data
        class InnerMusician {
            private String id;
        }
    }
}
```

---

GsonObject.java (this is the top-level class which contains all of the POJOs above):

```
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.List;

@Data
public class GsonObject {
    private Header       header;
    private List<Entity> entities;
}
```

---

Inside my calling class, this is the code that doesn't populate:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
GsonObject gsonObject = gson.fromJson(json, (Type) GsonObject.class);
```

---

The `gsonObject` internal header class is correctly populated with the timestamp but `List<GsonObject> entities` is null.

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you can cast `GsonObject` (the result of calling `fromJson`) to `Gson`?

Comment: Sorry, edited my question to address my issue, specifically.

Comment: This is an entirely different question, but also just a "typo". In JSON it's `entity`, in your class it's `entities`. Those need to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Savior pointed out, in JSON, attribute is `entity` and in your class it is `entities`.

Use `@SerializedName` in your class to map the java attribute to JSON attribute.

```
@SerializedName("entity")
private List<Entity> entities;
```